# Reshape Data into Time Series using R

Tags: r, time-series, reshape

I have a seemingly simple question that I can't figure out. I would like to take a dataset in which each time period has its own variable (i.e. column) for an observation and reformat it such that each observation has just one variable that ranges over time periods. My current data looks like:

```
obs <- 1:4
y1 <- 5:8
y2 <- 9:12  
data_matrix <- cbind(obs, y1, y2)
```

which produces:

```
     obs y1 y2
[1,]   1  5  9
[2,]   2  6 10
[3,]   3  7 11
[4,]   4  8 12
```

and I would like it to look like (also creating a time period variable, T):

```
     obs  T y2
[1,]   1  1  5
[2,]   1  2  9
[3,]   2  1  6
[4,]   2  2 10
[5,]   3  1  7
[6,]   3  2 11
[7,]   4  1  8
[8,]   4  2 12
```

Thanks for any advice on how to reshape this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your data:

```
data_matrix<-data.frame(data_matrix)
reshape(data_matrix,varying=list(2:3),times=names(data_matrix)[2:3],idvar="obs",v.names="value",direction="long")
```

returns:

```
     obs time value
1.y1   1   y1     5
2.y1   2   y1     6
3.y1   3   y1     7
4.y1   4   y1     8
1.y2   1   y2     9
2.y2   2   y2    10
3.y2   3   y2    11
4.y2   4   y2    12
```

You can then sort it by obs.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that `cbind()` is for appending columns and you are looking to combine both rows and columns. There are a lot of different ways to approach this, but if your example is actually this simple (ie: only these few columns) then it's easy to just create two data frames via `data.frame()` and then combine them via `rbind()`:

```
> rbind(data.frame(obs,y2=y1,T=1),data.frame(obs,y2,T=2))
  obs y2 T
1   1  5 1
2   2  6 1
3   3  7 1
4   4  8 1
5   1  9 2
6   2 10 2
7   3 11 2
8   4 12 2
```